# dom traversal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this html and want to traverse the dom and place a value in the span that has the

```
class="center"
```

after the page is loaded using jquery. I must take into consideration that the are other html on the same page with same structre as this. The only difference is that each of them has a unique td id. Here is the html:

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <td id="bankname">
  <div unselectable="on" style="-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:
   rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); width: 66px; " class=" select-area select-modify_select  
   select-focus ">
   <span class="left"></span>
   <span class="center">B.N.S.</span>
   <a class="select-opener"></a>
  </div>
 </td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#bankname span.center').text( newValue );
```

Comment: Same idea on the placeholder, how curious!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#bankname span.center').text( theValueYouWant );
});
```

This way you search for a `<span>` tag having `center` class inside `#bankname` element.

Comment: I would probably use `#bankname span.center` - it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#bankname span.center').text('Hello World!!');
```

I prefer **.html()** here as it is a bit faster than **.text()**

```
$('#bankname span.center').html('Hello World!!');
```